# Scroll past end of list

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-recyclerview

I currently have a `RecyclerView` which allows the user to scroll through a long list. However, the view stops scrolling right when it reaches the last item in the data-set.

**Question:** How can I allow the user to scroll further so that the last item in the `RecyvlerView` is able to scroll further up the screen?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "overscrolling." This behavior was introduced in Gingerbread.

To turn it on, you use

```
public void setOverScrollMode(int mode);
```

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode(int)):

> **public void setOverScrollMode (int mode)**
>
> Added in API level 9 Set the over-scroll mode for this view. Valid
>   over-scroll modes are OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS (default),
>   OVER_SCROLL_IF_CONTENT_SCROLLS (allow over-scrolling only if the view
>   content is larger than the container), or OVER_SCROLL_NEVER. Setting
>   the over-scroll mode of a view will have an effect only if the view is
>   capable of scrolling.
>
> Parameters mode   The new over-scroll mode for this view.

You can read more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOverScrollMode(int)).

Comment: Hmmm, I tried adding this to my recyclerView however it didn't have any affect. Is there a way to determine the amount of overscroll? Thank you for the reply!

Comment: @MatthewSteinhardt what mode did you put?

Comment: didn't work for me. i'm still unable to scroll past my last recyclerview item no matter what mode (always,never,ifContentScrolls)

Comment: That is not true - overscrolling is that translucent semicircle effect you get when trying to scroll past the end of the list. This setting can turn that effect on/off, but does not enable scrolling past the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

On your recyclerViewAdapter's `onBindViewHolder`, catch the last item with a condition on the `position` matching your `list.size() - 1` and then programatically set the bottom margin, thusly:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewsItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(position == getCurrentList().size() - 1){
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
                 (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) itemHolderRootView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin,layoutParams.topMargin,layoutParams.rightMargin, 300);
    }
}
```

You may want to multiply `300` bottom margin with your screen density through

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int bottomMargin = 300 * metrics.densityDpi;
```

since it'll vary among screens.

Comment: You'll want to also reset the margin to zero when it is not the last item. Otherwise if the last item view is reused, you'll end up with the margin in there.

Comment: Also, it's `metrics.density` you want, not `metrics.densityDpi `